# How to store signatures in a Solana account

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, signature, anchor-lang

Is there a cleaner way to store signatures in an account?
I mean instead of storing the 88 characters as a `String`. For instance Publickeys are stored as 32 Bytes instead of their corresponding 44 characters (Base58 encoded).

Can we do something similar for signatures to save space?

Answer (score 1):

Signatures can be stored as 64 bytes.

Simply decode it back, say using [`bs58`](https://crates.io/crates/bs58):

```
pub struct MyAccount {
  signature: [u8; 64],
}

let my_account = MyAccount {
  signature: bs58::decode("<your signature b58 string>").into_vec()?,
};
```